# what does "runed" mean? can anyone give another example sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

the lecturer is [saying clear](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=78)

> the gradient of this line is equal to the amount of that function that
>   increases in this interval divided by the length of the interval that
>   we're considering this description is often just condensed to the
>   expression rise over run where rise is the increase in the vertical
>   direction and run is the distance along the horizontal axis so both
>   rise here and `runed` down here

[merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/runed) confirmed it is a legitimate word, without giving more explanation, so, what does "runed" mean? can anyone give another example sentence?

Comment: He's saying **"run"** not "runed".   He's used the term "run" multiple times in the video, and clearly defined it in the same sentence "the distance along the horizontal axis".  It's a fairly standard term when talking about lines in algebra.  "Runed" is a word, but it's not math related.  It means "inscribed with [**runes**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rune)".  As you might expect, it's not a very common word.

Comment: Have you listened the time point yourself? He pronounced a 'd' very slowly and clearly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misunderstanding of a word used in a video.

Comment: Yes I've listened to the video.  You're hearing the "d" from the following word "down".  But it's really just basic logic, yeah?  Either the teacher is saying **"run"**, a term known to every native English-speaking student learning about the slope of a line, or he's using the fairly obscure term **"runed"**, which relates to an archaic form of writing, and which has nothing whatsoever to do with math.  Which do you think is more likely?

Comment: You got me! Please mv or cp your comments to answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already voted for the question to be closed.   I'm glad it's clear for you now!  :)

Comment: The entire passage quoted is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew said, the lecturer is saying "run", and the "d" from the following word "down".